# Rails app deployed using elastic beanstalk responds with "site can't be reached"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puma

I have built a rails app with the following stack:

1. Puma (application server) 3.0
2. Ruby on Rails 5.0
3. Postgresql 9.5.3

I tried deploying this application to aws elastic beanstalk and successfully did it. However, when I tried reaching the web address generated by the beanstalk, there is no hit on the application server. After a few minutes the browser throws "site can't be reached".

Here are the necessary logs:

*puma.log*

```
=== puma startup: 2017-01-17 18:10:06 +0000 ===
=== puma startup: 2017-01-17 18:10:06 +0000 ===
[1501] - Worker 0 (pid: 1504) booted, phase: 0
```

*/var/log/nginx/error.log*

```
2017/01/17 18:03:08 [warn] 703#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2017/01/17 18:25:00 [warn] 2043#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2017/01/17 18:25:00 [warn] 2050#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
```

*/var/app/containerfiles/logs/production.log*

```
D, [2017-01-17T18:10:02.564332 #1397] DEBUG -- :    (1.0ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(6778635641374256100);
D, [2017-01-17T18:10:02.574041 #1397] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
D, [2017-01-17T18:10:02.591019 #1397] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "ar_internal_metadata".* FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["key", :environment], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2017-01-17T18:10:02.596200 #1397] DEBUG -- :    (1.0ms)  BEGIN
D, [2017-01-17T18:10:02.598152 #1397] DEBUG -- :    (1.0ms)  COMMIT
D, [2017-01-17T18:10:02.599249 #1397] DEBUG -- :    (0.9ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(6778635641374256100)
```

This production.log stays as is despite multiple reloads. I have not been able to get any errors in any of the logs.

For further reference:

Here are my few other files:

*config/puma.rb*

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/
  # deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

*Gemfile*

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Ruby gem
 ruby '2.3.1'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
# Gemfile for password hashing
gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.11'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.5'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'select2-rails'
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
# Upload files
gem 'carrierwave', '>= 1.0.0.rc', '< 2.0'
# Image resizing
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.5', '>= 4.5.1'
# Image upload in production
gem 'fog-aws'
# Autoprefix CSS
gem "autoprefixer-rails"
# Google Maps API
gem 'geocoder'
# Redis
gem 'redis', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.1'
# For postgres full text search
gem 'pg_search'
# Font awesome support
gem "font-awesome-rails"
# Google oauth-2
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"
# Facebook omniauth
gem 'omniauth-facebook'

group :production do
  gem 'remote_syslog_logger'
end

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem 'better_errors', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.1'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'rails_layout'
  gem 'seed_dump', '~> 3.2', '>= 3.2.4'
  gem 'rubocop', '~> 0.44.1', require: false
  gem 'binding_of_caller', '~> 0.7.2'
  gem 'meta_request'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 0.10.1'
  gem 'brakeman', :require => false
  gem 'bullet'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '0.1.1'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.9'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Apart from that, I have tried a few things after my own personal research on google and stackoverflow:

I appended the following to my puma config file(*puma.rb*):

```
bind "unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock"
pidfile "/var/run/puma/my_app.sock"
```

I even tried changing my controller for the root path to render a simple hello, instead of trying to get data from the database. But the main issue seems to be that the request does not reach the application as evident from zero log entries in *production.log*.

I also tried removing the version number for puma provided in the *Gemfile* hoping that an updated version could fix this issue.

I also tried restarting the nginx server as well as the application server multiple times. But nothing seems to be able to throw a meaningful error.

To be sure that it is not a database issue, I ssh-ed into the eb cli, and used the rails console. The console worked just fine. So, it is not a database issue.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me out, and atleast get me a meaningful error in the logs.

EDIT 1:
As asked by Sahil, the nginx.conf file is:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.fedora.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    index   index.html index.htm;

    server {
        listen       80 ;
        listen       [::]:80 ;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
        #
        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl;
#        server_name  localhost;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        # It is *strongly* recommended to generate unique DH parameters
#        # Generate them with: openssl dhparam -out /etc/pki/nginx/dhparams.pem 2048
#        #ssl_dhparam "/etc/pki/nginx/dhparams.pem";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:SEED:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!RSAPSK:!aDH:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:!SRP;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }


}
```

Apart from that, in my production.rb file:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

EDIT 2:

I opened the url in my friend's laptop. It opened up. It seems the problem is with my system proxy. Now I could remove my system proxy, but I can't be sure for my users who would be visiting my website. Is there a way elastic beanstalk be used with system proxy? Meanwhile, I will fondle over the internet for the same.

EDIT 3:
I tried opening the website from safari in my laptop. It works. But it does not work from Google Chrome.

EDIT 4:
I cleared cache from my browser and it worked! A lesson learnt.

Comment: Have you setup your ngnix.conf properly? If you can also post your nginx.conf file?

Comment: @sahil please do have a look..I have added the nginx configuration file.

Comment: root should point to, `/path/to/code_folder/public`. Here is a [template](https://gist.github.com/sahil290791/291298c55fd1dcf59cfb472c6c3a215a) which I use for multiple apps running on Pushion passenger, Nginx and Rails.

Comment: chaning this  `config.force_ssl = true` to `false` solved the problem. I spent days trying to figure this

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a 504 gateway timeout error after deploying my rails app to elastic beanstalk. Adding a file named "Procfile" (no extension) in the root directory of the app with the contents

```
web: bundle exec puma -C /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/pumaconf.rb
```

solved my issue.